# Travis-CI, PHP behat & mink + phantomjs, Apache not using environment php version

Tags: travis-ci

Repo: https://github.com/samsoncms/cms

Trying to run web-application automated behat tests, locally everything works fine, but when I install apache on travis, then set then default host, it always uses "PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18"

What should I configure in .travis.yml to set apache to work to current environment php version?

Manual travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Apache-%2B-PHP does not work